# If $\int_{\Bbb R}k(x)dx=1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(k\star g(f(x)))=g(L)$ right?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f,g,k:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be non-negative continuous functions. Suppose $k:\Bbb R\to[0,\infty)$ is a symmetric probability denstiy function satisfying

$$ \int_{\Bbb R}k(x)dx = 1$$

and suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$, and $g$ is continuous near $L$. Then the integral convolution:

$$ I(x) = \int_{\Bbb R} k(x-y) g(f(y)) dy \tag{1}$$

Must approach $g(L)$ as $x\to\infty$ right?

---

**My attempt.** Let $\epsilon>0$. We need to find $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that if $x>x_0$ then the result expression (1) less than $\varepsilon$ distance to $g(L)$.

Let $\epsilon_1>0$. Since $g$ is continuous and $f(x)\to L$, for all $\delta_1>0$ there exists $y_0$ such that $y>y_0$ implies $|f(y)-L|<\delta_1$, then since $g$ is continuous, we get $|g(f(y))-g(L)|<\epsilon_1$. Hence we will only consider $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $y>y_0$.

Now we can bound our integral:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_{\Bbb R} k(x-y) g(f(y)) dy &\geq \int_{y_0}^{\infty} k(x-y) g(f(y)) dy\\
& \geq \int_{y_0}^{\infty} k(x-y) (g(L)-\epsilon_1) dy\\
& = (g(L)-\epsilon_1)\int_{y_0}^{\infty} k(x-y) dy
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

Let $\epsilon_2>0$. Now choose $x_0$ such that the integral

$$ 1-\epsilon_2 < \int_{y_0}^{\infty} k(x-y) < 1$$

This is always possible since $k$ vanishes at $\pm\infty$. But I'm not sure how to prove this. Anyway, just suppose it is true. Then we get a further bound:

$$ \begin{aligned}
\int_{\Bbb R} k(x-y) g(f(y)) dy 
&\geq (g(L)-\epsilon_1)\int_{y_0}^{\infty} k(x-y) dy \\
&\geq (g(L)-\epsilon_1)(1-\epsilon_2) \\
&\geq g(L) - \epsilon_1 - g(L)\epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1\epsilon_2
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

I think it is clear enough that for any $\epsilon>0$ we could bound the error term $\epsilon_1 - g(L)\epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1\epsilon_2$ by that amount. However I only found a lower bound, and I have no idea how to find an upper bound.

Do you have any ideas? Or can I use a sledgehammer theorem, something like "convolution with probability density preserves limits"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g$ in bounded in $(0,\infty)$ or $f$ bounded in $(-\infty,0)$, the conclusion should follow from dominated convergence since the range of $f$ is contained in a compact interval and so, $g\circ f$ is bounded. Apply dominated convergence to the integral
$$ k*(g\circ f)(x)=\int k(y) g(f(x-y))\,dy$$
If you need to avoid the dominated convergence, notice that
$\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int^\infty_bk(y)\,dy=0$. Let $a>0$ be such that
$x>a$ implies
\begin{aligned}
 |g\circ(x)-g(L)|&<\varepsilon\\
\int^\infty_x k(y)&<\varepsilon
\end{aligned}
Then, for $x\geq 2a$
$$
\left| \int k(y)(g(f(x-y))-g(L))dy\right| \leq
\varepsilon\int_{y<x-a}k(y)\,dy + M\int_{y>x-a}k(y)\leq \varepsilon+M\varepsilon
$$
where $M$ is an upper bound to $g\circ f$.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to apply the DCT? I thought DCT relates to a sequence of converging functions $(f_n)\to f$, so what are my $f_n$ here exactly?

Comment: Assuming boundedness of $f$, $\phi_x(y):=g\circ f(x-y)$.  Then $|\phi_x|\leq \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}|g\circ f|$.  $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\phi_x(y)=g(L)$.

Comment: That is a great proof, and makes my work a lot easier. Thanks!